# Visual Studio snippet file ASP.NET Web Forms Code Language

Tags: asp.net, code-snippets

The snippet file has an element where the language has to be specified and depending on this, in the Tools->Snippet Manager the snippet is shown or not according to the Language selector.

```
<Code Language="???">
```

What to put there in order to be able to see it in Snippet Manager when 'ASP.NET Web Forms' is selected?

Answer (score 0):

for c#, use:

```
<Code Language="CSharp">
```

for vb, use:

```
<Code Language="VB">
```

Note that you need to put in a title - else while it will show up, it will not have any title text.

So, say this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>Using block rstData</Title>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="VB">
        <![CDATA[

        Dim rstData As New DataTable
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(strCon)
            Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
                conn.Open()
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
                rstData.TableName = strSQL
            End Using
        End Using
    
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

And then in code editor, you see this:

[image]